# Is the notion of an absolutely force-free motion a purely theoretical one?

Tags: kinematics

If not, what would be a scenario in our universe where a particle would truly experience it?

Comment: Are you talking about no forces what so ever, or a _net force_ identical to zero?

Comment: The questions is not sufficiently well defined - I vote to put this on hold until there are further clarifications. Is the questions asking whether:
1. There is a test particle that - in the Classical sense - experiences zero acceleration at some point.
2. There is a particle that - in the Quantum sense - couples only to fields that are locally identically zero at a given spacetime point.
3. As above but with locally zero spacetime curvature.

Comment: @Marius Ladegård Meyer, the former, but out of curiosity I wouldn't mind hearing about the latter as well

Comment: @Akerai, I meant (1) but I'm not familiar enough with some concepts you mention in (2) and (3) - I'm not a physicist

Comment: I think it's a rather tricky question to ask as you will get drowned in inconsistent answers depending on what framework people work in. For all intents and purposes force-free motion will always be only an approximation to something much more involved and complicated that in the end does not matter. At the end of the day physics is here to describe the world as we can currently measure it - not to explain it.

Comment: To my knowledge any answer that will claim exactly force-free motion to exist (or not) will do so in the context of a particular mathematical framework.

Comment: @Akerai you second comment above is an interesting answer in and of itself. Could you however give examples of such frameworks in which the answer might differ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101667/discussion-between-acros-and-akerai).

Answer (score 1):

No, it’s not purely theoretical. In General Relativity gravity is not a force. So photons of the cosmic microwave background have been traveling for 13 billion years across the universe undisturbed by any force or, more properly, interaction. (Not just no *net* force; no force at all!) The last one they experienced was the electromagnetic one that made them scatter from charged particles about 380,000 years after the Big Bang.

Comment: But isn't the OP talking about particles having rest mass, not photons?

Comment: @G. Smith, that's interesting, I wasn't aware of the fact that gravity isn't a force in GR. Could you recommend accessible resources discussing the matter?

Comment: @Bob D, I probably should have specified and yes, I had particles with rest mass in mind when I asked the question, but suspected certain photons may qualify so it's nice to hear confirmation

Comment: I think it's a bit of an opaque answer to claim that the photons do not interact with the matter field past recombination. It's just that the magnitude is >effectively< zero. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Akerai Sorry, I don’t understand what is opaque about my answer, or what you think the CMB has been doing.

Comment: @acros See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force#Gravity_as_a_fictitious_force) about gravity being a fictitious force in GR. Mathematically, particles moving under the influence of gravity are just following geodesics in curved spacetime, which means they are traveling in straight lines at constant velocity, but through curved spacetime. *True* forces like electromagnetism cause them to deviate from these geodesics.

Comment: @G.Smith What I am saying is that CMB interacts with charged particles still, otherwise we would not have been capable of measuring it. It's just that the interaction is on average negligible. Not identically zero.

Comment: @Akerai Yes, correct, it interacted with our instruments. I meant that it didn’t interact for the previous 13.7 billion years, or any such interaction is so small that it isn’t showing up in our measurements.

Comment: @G.Smith I agree with you now. I know that I am nitpicking, but the question seems to be aiming for exactly this. If there is any spacetime point where some particle-field fully decouples from every other field - and I think the answer to that is no. That said, it is a non-physical question to begin with. I elaborated on that further in the comments of the original question.

Comment: Thanks @G.Smith, your explanation actually makes a lot of sense, I just never thought about it from this angle.

Answer (score 0):

In order for a particle to experience absolutely force-free motion, the net force applied to it must be zero.

I'm not a cosmologist, but I don't believe there is any place in the universe absolutely free of the force of gravity. Moreover, the celestial bodies that create gravitational forces are constantly moving, so I would think that a net gravitational force at any specific location cannot remain zero for long.

So while it may be possible for a particle to *momentarily* experience absolutely force-free motion,  I would say there would be no scenario in our universe where it could *continuously* experience absolutely force-free motion.

Hope this helps.

Comment: GR doesn't describe gravity as a force.

Comment: @Ben Crowell Yes Ben but I’m answering in the context of Newtonian mechanics, not GR. Do you see anything wrong with that in the context of the OP question?